# Lifetime annotations, or &str vs String

Tags: rust, lifetime

I have a little library that exports a struct with lifetime annotations. Now I tried to use it from another program, but it seems like I now need to use lifetime annotations there, too. Essentially I'm doing this:

```
// in my lib
struct Foo<'a> {
    baz: &'a str
}

// another program
struct Bar {
    foo: Foo
}
```

Which says `Bar` must define a lifetime for `Foo`:

```
<anon>:6:10: 6:13 error: wrong number of lifetime parameters: expected 1, found 0 [E0107]
<anon>:6     foo: Foo
                  ^~~
```

This is easy to fix:

```
struct Bar<'a> {
    foo: Foo<'a>
}
```

But this would mean I now also have to define lifetimes for anything that uses `Bar`, and so on, correct? And if this is true, is there any way to fix this, other than using types that don't require explicit lifetimes? Or would it be better to use owned types like `String` anyway?

A bit of background, I used `&str` because I had to call a function that required as an argument. While converting them is no problem, it is actually a `Vec<(&str, &str)>`, so my idea was to get rid of the conversion by using the correct types in the first place. I have a feeling that was the wrong decision, but what do I know... :)

Comment: Note that there are "cheap" conversions in Rust; by convention those are indicated by method names starting by `as_`. For example `String::as_slice` yields a `&str`, which borrows the `String` it comes from.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yeah there's currently no way around the bubbling up of explicit lifetimes. The way to think about it is that `Foo` needs to be explicit about which lifetime is being associated with it, since the `baz` field depends on it, so that for example, the compiler knows to stop you if you try to make `Foo` live longer than the data `baz` refers to, or so that you could have methods that return references that "live as long as baz lives." If you then embed `Foo` into `Bar`, now `Bar` needs an explicit lifetime because `Foo` depends on it.

If `Foo` is "owning" the string, meaning if a `Foo` should be able to stand on its own independent of any possible lifetime (e.g. scope), then it should indeed be a `String`. Converting from a `String` to a slice is very inexpensive, since the slice is merely a view into existing data.

If however, you're *always* constructing `Foo` based on existing data which is tied to a scope (e.g. a string slice that was passed to the function containing the `Foo` instances, etc.) and a `Foo` instance doesn't need to live past the scope of that existing data, then if you made it a `String` you would have to convert the slice to a `String` (which is relatively expensive compared to the reverse) only to then convert it back to a slice at the point of use, in which case you should keep it as a slice. You certainly shouldn't incur this performance penalty simply to avoid having to type the explicit lifetimes.

You'll find that types with explicit lifetimes are pretty common, so while it does seem alarming at first, you'll get used to it.